# virtual servers in nginx and its implications

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to spin off multiple virtual servers for my different needs in nginx.

I understand that virtual servers are to be created for each domain, at the minimum I will have virtual server one for PROD and one for TEST.

Also is it advisable to create more virtual servers each for Incoming requests [reverseProxy] and for Outgoing requests[Proxy] ?

Is there any performance implications upon spinning off more virtual servers. If yes what is the ideal number of virtual servers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think virtual-servers are handled by worker threads. And the no. of worker threads that can be spawned depends on the CPU cores and memory available. Hence you would need more CPU and memory for larger number of virtual-servers.

Offcourse the above assumes reasonable load on every virtual-server.